# How do I get the DC coefficient from a jpg using the jpg library?

Tags: c++, jpeg, compression

I am new to this stuff, but I need to get the dc-coefficient from a jpeg using the jpeg library?
I was told as a hint that the corresponding function is in jdhuff.c, but I can't find it. I tried to find a decent article about the jpg library where I can get this, but no success so far.

So I hope you guys can help me a bit and point me to either some documentation or have a hint.
So, here is what I know:

A jpg picture consists of 8x8 Blocks. That are 64 Pixels. 63 of it are named AC and 1 is named DC. Thats the coefficient. The position is at array[0][0].

But how do I exactly read that with the jpg library? I am using C++.

edit:
This is what I have so far:

```
read_jpeg::read_jpeg( const std::string& filename )
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;                // File-Pointer
    jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;   // jpeg decompression parameters
    JSAMPARRAY buffer;              // Output row-buffer
    int row_stride = 0;             // physical row width
    my_error_mgr jerr;              // Custom Error Manager


    // Set Error Manager
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr.pub);
    jerr.pub.error_exit = my_error_exit;

    // Handle longjump
    if (setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer)) {

        // JPEG has signaled an error. Clean up and throw an exception.
        jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
        fclose(fp);
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: jpeg has reported an error.");
    }   

    // Open the file
    if ( (fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL )
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Error: Cannot read '" <<  filename.c_str() << "' from the specified location!";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

    // Initialize jpeg decompression
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

    // Show jpeg where to read the data
    jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, fp);

    // Read the header
    jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

    // Decompress the file
    jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

    // JSAMPLEs per row in output buffer
    row_stride = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;

    // Make a one-row-high sample array 
    buffer = (*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)((j_common_ptr) &cinfo, JPOOL_IMAGE, row_stride, 1);

    // Read image using jpgs counter
    while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) 
    {

         // Read the image
         jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
    }

    // Finish the decompress 
    jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);

    // Release memory
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);

    // Close the file 
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the standard API. With libjpeg API the closest you can get is raw pixel data of Y/Cb/Cr channels.

To get coefficients' data you'd need to hack the `decode_mcu` function (or its callers) to save the data decoded there.